# Setup for emacs org-mode outside .emacs file

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to set up a project to be published as HTML using org-mode.

I don't want to litter my `.emacs` with project definitions, and I was wondering where I could put the `(setq org-publish-project-alist)` variable.

Can I somehow put it in the same dir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ryan McGeary describes what I think is a good way to [organize emacs startup files](http://emacsblog.org/2007/10/07/declaring-emacs-bankruptcy/).

Update:
The domain **emacsblog.org** expired :( 
You can look at the [cached copy](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:HyA_XUDcZgUJ:emacsblog.org/2007/10/07/declaring-emacs-bankruptcy/%20%22Ryan%20McGeary%22%20declaring%20emacs%20bankruptcy&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca) of the originally linked page.

Comment: both links have been lost to linkrot, archive.org has a cached copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20200223220435/http://emacsblog.org/2007/10/07/declaring-emacs-bankruptcy/

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a new file in your .emacs.d (or whereever) and do a load-file in your .emacs file.

-- EDIT --

For example, you could have the following in your .emacs

```
(load (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp/personal-org-mode-stuff.el"))
```

and then put all of your customization stuff in ~/.emacs.d/lisp/personal-org-mode-stuff.el and it will load that file and import all of your .emacs

Another poster also posted a link to a description of how to add your lisp files to the load path and require them.

Comment: good idea. But how? :) Emacs newbie. Would something like `(load "myfile.el" nil t t)` work?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set it manually at all, but rather use Emacs' [customize](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) mechanism to control the value of this variable, your .emacs file will not be cluttered if you add the following two lines to your .emacs:

```
(setq custom-file "~/.emacs-custom.el")
(load custom-file 'noerror)
```

Although some might claim that it's kind of ironic that you have to *add* two lines two your .emacs file to declutter it that way...